# How to detect if picturebox is beyond the forms width?

Tags: c#, picturebox

Hi guys I have searched for an answer but I have not found a particular answer that would help me. So I am asking this question.

My question is how do you detect if your picturebox moves outside the window or form.

Each tick of my timer does:

```
picturebox.Left += 10;
if (picturebox.Left > this.Width)
{
    picturebox.Left = 0;
}
```

But this code only goes to the right side and only detects if the picturebox went out on the right side of the form.

I have tried doing something like lets say I'm moving the picturebox to the left and it went out of the screen, this is the code I have got and this doesnt give any error but it will move my image so fast then.

```
picturebox.Left -= 10;
if (picturebox.Left > this.width || picturebox.Left < this.Width)
{
    picturebox.Left = 0;
}
```

This piece of code doesnt work for me either:

```
picturebox.Right < this.Width
```

Please help,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way...

```
    private int direction = -1;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        direction = direction * -1;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        picturebox.Left += direction * 10;

        if (!this.ClientRectangle.IntersectsWith(picturebox.Bounds))
        {
            if (direction == -1)
                picturebox.Left = this.ClientRectangle.Width;
            else
                picturebox.Left = -picturebox.Width;
        }
    }
```

Comment: woah! i just did this on my MVC assignment and woo! thanks to you now my images change everytime it slides and goes out of the form! so amazing. thank you!.I have learnt something from your code. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
private bool IsControlInsideClientArea(Control c)
{
    return this.ClientRectangle.Contains(this.RectangleToClient(c.RectangleToScreen(c.ClientRectangle)));
}
```